# Changing two parts of the text in a large number of cells

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have long formulas in a large number of cells in several spreadsheets. I want to remove some text in the beginning portion of each formula and I want to remove text which is an apostrophe only (') in a later part of each formula. In summary in this instance I am seeking to remove long references to another workbook from these formulas and allow the workbook to work independently of the other workbook.  I tried find replace but it did not perform the task.  I am not seeking to add new text to replace the text or the apostrophe. I would like to remove the test from each spreadsheet individually.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Super User,,, please [Edit] your  post & add sample Formula,, along with Screen Shot  of expected output, help us to understand the issue to fix it.

Comment: Could you provide a sample about this problem?

Comment: Thanks Lee, 
Following is an example of a cell's text which I want to change from: 
='D:\Capital\Merge 201910823\[StockModel_v8aTemplate Original - Copy from 20181231F.xlsm]DailyEC1'!F2019
To:
=DailyEC1!F2019
Thus one is removing the first portion of the text and also the apostrophe in the conserved later portion of the text.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add further information. Comments don't have the necessary formatting for displaying formulas properly.

Answer (score 0):

You have presumably differing text for the beginning text that you wish to remove. So simply using `SUBSTITUTE()` to remove it likely won't work. Also, probably you don't want to deal with Search and Replace choking because of the `'` that also needs removed. (Choking because with it in the after-Replace material, it is not a valid formula and an error is given ending the Search and Replace without even the interim result.)

So, handle the first part by noticing the unique characteristic of the text you need to remove (path names with file names, apparently), regardless of its differing from formula to formula, because it references different files:

The `]` at the end is unique because of how Excel formed these references in the first place.

So use `FIND()` to locate it, subtract that location's numerical value from the length of the cell's text (`LEN()`)to get the length of the portion you need to remain (handling the `'` later!), and wrap that in a `RIGHT()` to end up with a perfect answer except for that final apostrophe.

Wrap all that in a `SUBSTITUTE()` function to substitute a "nothing" — `""` — for the apostrophe.

All done:    (assumes the value to adjust is in cell A1)

```
=SUBSTITUTE( RIGHT(A1, LEN(A1) - FIND("]",A1) ), "'", "")
```